# SharePoint 2010 Meeting Menu

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, calendar, meeting-workspace, editing-menu

I have a question about a SharePoint meeting menu.
In our office I should replicate a SharePoint 2010 site without accessing it with
SharePoint Designer. The site is here for coordinating meetings. Also some features
of SharePoint are restricted. (risk policy)

I've replicated about 50% of the content but now I'm stuck with a menu element.
The element is directly below the menu.

Here is a picture:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjFzX.png]

After hours of searching the web I've decided to ask the community.

Would be happy if someone could help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer.

When you're creating a (repeating) meeting in SharePoint, you have the option to generate a workspace. You have to tick the little cross on the bottom of the form. With the Save button it's going to redirect you to a new page on which you can set the name for the workspace.

Here's a screen:

[image: Generate Meeting Workspace]